# Succeeding adverbs

Tags: adverbs, word-order

In a thesis by a German student, I saw some interesting usage of succeeding adverbs, are they correct or normal for the ear of a native-speaker?

> The following characteristics therefore hold for the extracted LTAG as well as PLTAG grammar, **except, of course,** the specifications about the prediction trees, which LTAG does not use.
>
> The created resources are **however also** applicable to parsing with other variants of TAG, and hence of interest to a broad audience.
>
> The German PLTAG resources presented in this work are **hence also** useful for other variants of TAG.
>
> Elementary trees are allowed to contain empty words, but **only if also** an overt lexical item is present.

Comment: Tose sentences all sound fine to a native ear, however the **also** in **only if also** is not necessary.

Comment: "hence" is formal register and somewhat dated.  The placement of the word **also** is awkward but not ungrammatical in "but only if also an overt lexical item is present".  It would typically be "but only if an overt lexical item is also present".  The first two sentences are fine; the second could do with some commas: are, however, also ....

Answer (score 2):

Your first three examples seem okay, though I'd say that "except" is a preposition, not an adverb.

In your last example, "also" is misplaced - it should be placed immediately before, or after, "present".